# WIF 3.5 + 4.5 compatibility

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.5, wif, claims-based-identity

There seems to be plenty of examples of how to migrate from 3.5 to 4.5 but I'm struggling with a particular scenario.

I have several existing asp.net sites that are using WIF 3.5 to implement federated identity with an adfs 2.0 server.

Single sign in, and passive single sign out (wscleanup1.0) is all working fine.

No we are developing a new asp.net site and seeing as it's a new project we thought we should use WIF 4.5.

Single sign in is still working fine across all these apps.  It doesn't matter which one you sign into first all of the others recognise the token and can read the claims.

We are, however, seeing an issue with single sign out.

If I initiate the signout from the site using WIF 4.5 everything works as expected.  You're signed out of every app you have used during that session.

If, however, I initiate the signout from one of the sites using WIF 3.5 all of the sites using WIF 3.5 sign out as expected but the site using WIF 4.5 remains logged in.

Is this something that should be possible or are there incompatibilities between the versions which means it will never work?

I read here that the format of the cookie had changed but that's a year old now so I was looking for a more current answer.

[Unable to decrypt claims cookie from .NET 4.5 to .NET 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754136/unable-to-decrypt-claims-cookie-from-net-4-5-to-net-3-5/21757852#21757852)